# How to call a virtual method overridden in python from C++ using SWIG

Tags: swig

My C++ class:

```
class Base {
public:
virtual void foo(int);
};
```

In the python module, I have a class that derives from above and overrides foo.

```
class PyDerived(Base):
 ...
 def foo(self):
   ...
```

Then I create an object of this derived class using a factory method that is defined in python module like this:

```
def createObject():
  m = PyDerived()
  return m
```

With this PyObject in C++ code, I want to call foo and I want foo in python module to be executed. Is this possible? If so how?

(I already tried calling virtual methods from python which dispatch the actual call to a C++ method, but that does not match my requirements)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to enable the SWIG "directors" feature for the class `Base` containing the `virtual` method. You can read about it in the documentation [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_directors).

The documentation will tell you that you need to add two things to the SWIG interface file:

1. At the very beginning, edit the `%module` directive to enable the use of directors at all:

   `%module(directors="1") your_modulename`
2. Before the declaration of the class `Base` or the corresponding `%include` directive, put the following to enable the directors feature for that class:

   `%feature("director") Base;`

Comment: I have done that already, but how does it allow one to call virtual methods from C++? Do I have to include the header file created in my code and call the virtual method? I already tried doing that, but that header uses things in the swig namespace without even including swig header. This made me think that it is not the correct way to do this.

Comment: I suggest getting your SWIG wrappers compiled and working first. Then, enabling the directors is just the two steps above, no need to change anything else (i.e., additional headers, etc.). The way directors work under the hood is explained in the documentation, but you don't really need to worry about that.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't fully understand your question. In C++, in a function, say `void test(Base &base)` that takes a `Base &` as argument, just call the method `base.foo(0)`. From Python, pass a `PyDerived` to the C++ function, i.e., call `>>> module.test(PyDerived())`. The call to `base.foo(0)` will then execute the python function. Perhaps you need to define `def foo(self, i):...` in Python to make the arguments compatible with the C++ function.

Comment: Thanks. I have got the python part of it compiled properly. I can import that to python and use it properly. My problem is, from C++ code, to be able to call foo, I need a C++ Base object. But from the factory what I get is a PyObject. how do I use that to call foo from c++?

Comment: According to your suggestion, the python does an up call to C++ and then C++ code calls the virtual method. What I would prefer to do is to call foo using the PyObject that I get from the factory which return a PyDerived. Not sure if this is possible? For both approaches, the C++ code would have to know about PyDerived type (C++ version). To do this, I will have to include the header that gets generated in the C++ application. Is this the intended way to do this? Why doesn't this header include required swig headers? I could not find any documentation detailing how to do this.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to include the code that you want to work, but that you currently can't get to work. Do you understand the concept of SWIG directors?